# Batch update a document in solr (django webapp)

Tags: django, solr, celery

I have several tables in mysql which I have denormalized and indexed in a solr. That means rows from multiple tables form one document in solr. When a request comes it may update multiple tables in mysql but my goal is to fire a single request to solr to update the index for each request. I have looked at django signals to sync index with mysql. But it will not serve the purpose of one update to solr index. What are the other options I should look into? What is the ideal way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve the above by adding a common signal handler for all the models

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Model1)
@receiver(post_save, sender=Model2)
@receiver(post_save, sender=Model3)
def handler(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    redis_connection.set(current_thread().name, instance.id)
```

And then in a SolrUpdateMiddleware

```
class SolrUpdateMiddleware(object):
    def process_response(self, request, response):
        id = redis_connection.get(current_thread().name)
        update_solr(id)
        redis_connection.delete(current_thread().name)
        return response
```

So now for a particular request, only one update will go to solr. Right now I am using a key value pair. I can use a set if I want to refresh multiple documents in one request.